# trying to installing xsim package within latex

Tags: pycxsimulator

I am having trouble using the xsim package it will just not recognise it as a package can anybody shed any light on this?

```
\usepackage{xsim}
```

and I get  the error xsim.sty not found

Comment: You have to install it. What's your operating system?